# Коллбек settimeout перестает вызываться

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

У меня есть проект на nodeJS v11.1.0, и имеется асинхронный вызов таймера

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
```

Вот пример функции как я её использую:

```
const taskEat = async (player, item) => {
    if (player.foodTimeout > Date.now()) return

    player.foodTimeout = Date.now() + 1000 * 5;

    await inventory.useItem(player, item);
    await sleep(5000);
    player.call('foodFinished');
}
```

По какой-то неизвестной причине callback с resolve не вызывается по всему проекту. Это происходит в рандомное время, иногда через пару минут после старта проекта, а иногда через пару дней происходят зависания. И это не всегда, практически это невозможно повторить в одиночку через дебаггер. Раньше когда мы заметили о такой проблеме, не сильно придавали значение, ведь зависало где-то на пару минут и потом отвичало. Сейчас же оно зависает на 30 минут, а порой вообще не отвисает после одного часа с момента зависания. Пробовали также использовать библиотеку bluebird с функцией `.delay()`, однако это не изменило ситуацию, таймеры продолжают зависать. При этом сам проект спокойно работает, промисы, функции и прочее работает без проблем. Даже `setInterval` работает без проблем.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? И почему вообще `setTimeout` может зависнуть

Comment: линканите как Вы вызываете `sleep`

Comment: Изменил пост с примером функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда попробуйте использовать метод `queueMicrotask`, а именно переписать таймер так:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => queueMicrotask( () => setTimeout(r, ms) ));
```

Comment: А как микротаски могут исправить проблему с тем, что таймеры зависают?

Comment: @Jengas, этот вариант лишь в теории. теперь промис будет возвращать не макротаску, а микротаску, что поставит Ваш `setTimeout` в приоритет. Но это, конечно же, всё равно не дает ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: @Jengas, так Вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: на проекте уже второй день не зависают таймеры после микротасков. Возможно это хорошая победа с кослытем в руках. А если серьезно, эта функция каким-то чудом работает